Tagging pictures linked to a person that is not directly depicted in
When a person you know is depicted in a photo, you can use tags with the personal name and surname to archive it and succesfully retrieve it.
Let's suppose to have a picture that represents a bike. You know that the bike belongs to your friend, that is out of the frame. And you don't want to miss this link over the years.
What would it be the best tagging solution to label that picture as somehow linked to your friend (or any other person), without using a tag with the personal name (used only when the person is clearly visible in the photo)? In other words, how would you express a connection/link with another entity expressed by a regular tag?

Define "best" tagging solution. "Best" in what terms? Cost of implementation? Ease of use to query/access that data in the future and cross-reference it with other meta-meta-tagging?

@scottbb I would certainly say in terms of avoiding as much as possible ambiguities and/or conflicts with other known tags, in terms of interoperability and also of implementation (basically something the average user can afford; low-level coding is accepted)
